# Footer does not display for report header with subreport

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

My report has 5 Report Headers. 4 of these headers have SubReports. Now I want a footer to show and print on all pages. But when I add a footer, it only displays on the 1st Report Header without a SubReport and on the rest of the details pages in my report.

Comment: which footer? report or page?

Comment: I using a page footer

Answer (score 0):

To display a header/footer on *every* page, use the **Page Header** or **Page Footer** sections.

The Report Header will only display at the beginning of a report, and the Report Footer will only display at the end.

Comment: I have added a page footer to my main report and it is not displaying on my Report Headers pages that have subreports on them. It displays fine on my Report Headers page that does not have a subreport. I need it to be on all pages of the report.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your Design View?

Comment: http://www.freezer-temperature.com/Capture.PNG  ReportHeader6 & 7 do not show the footer. Section 2 (with no subreport) does show the footer